# Need to hide the grand total(rows/columns) bar in Tableau

Tags: hide, bar-chart, tableau-api

Need to hide the grand total(rows/columns) bar and show only labels for grand total. I need to sort the column as per the values(measures) and need to hide the bars for grand total row/column i.e. I do not want to show any bars for the grand totals, just the labels. Please find the below screenshot. Also find the URL for Tableau workbook: https://community.tableau.com/message/730696#730696

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Max and Min function, although it worked for time being but not a long term solution as when the data will not be there then it will not give correct result.

Answer (score 1):

On the top toolbar: Analysis -> Totals -> Uncheck as needed.

Comment: i think unchecking totals under Analysis will remove totals from sheet. it seems he want to display totals with only labels. and don't want to display  bars.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second measure to be the bar for the chart that has the following formula:

If size() = 1 then 0 else  end

This will give at able calculation that, provided there are at least 2 bars to compare in the chart, will keep the grand total without a bar. Then, put the actual measure in the text label area to get the number to show up.